# Little bit confused about the math behind this function

Tags: c, math

So I've been looking at this function that converts Cartesian coordinates to polar and the if statement that says `if x == 0 and y>0 then theta == pi/2`.

However, if one wants to calculate theta it simply follows the form:

```
theta = atan(y/x).
```

What is confusing me is that if `x == 0` this function is immediately undefined? since you are dividing by `0` this should tend to infinity right?

So how is it that in this function it states that if `x ==0 and y>0` it always equals pi/2?

It's probably so basic and I'm just complicating way to much...

Thanks in advance.

```
void carttopolar(float x, float y, double *radptr, double *thetaptr){
    float theta;
    *radptr = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if(x==0){
        if(y==0){
            theta = 0.0;
        }
        else if(y>0){
            theta = M_PI_2;
        }
        else{
            theta = -M_PI_2;
        }
    }
    else{
        theta = atan(y/x);
    }
    *thetaptr = theta;
}
```

Comment: You may be confusing this function with the `tangent` function. This one calculates polar coordinates for a point given in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Consider using `atan2` instead, defined everywhere on R².

Comment: divide by zero is bad, it won't give you a useful answer ever... if x==0 then theta will be either -M_PI_2 or M_PI_2 depending on the sign of y

Comment: I think that atan2 isn't stdlib (pre C11), but a common extension right?

Comment: Yes, and if (x == 0 && y < 0) the value is 3*pi/2 or -pi/2, depending on the range.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: `atan2()` was in 7th Edition UNIX™ (circa 1979), and in C89, as well as C99 and C11.

Comment: This solution only handles 2 of 4 quadrants correctly.  When x < 0, this fails to generate the correct value.

Comment: @Bentoy13 `atan2()` is the way to go, but IIR, it is not well defined for `atan2(+/-0,+/-0)`;

Comment: Corner issue: `if(x==0){ ...` mostly provides a good answer when `x` is `0.0`, but wrong answers when `x == -0.0` or `y == -0.0`.  `atan2()` typically handles these obscure cases.

Comment: @chux The norm ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011 defines the special values for theoretical undefined values of atan2, see [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atan2.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that atan is the inverse of tan and tan does actually generate infinite values at some points, here's a picture:
[image: a picture]

The code is catching the cases where you would feed an infinite argument into atan and returning the angle that would give infinity (+/- pi/2 gives positive or negative infinity respectively).

The generally accepted way to do this is to just use the `atan2` function instead.

Answer (score 2):

This code is assuming that any positive number divided by zero is positive infinity, and any negative number divided by zero is negative infinity. It special cases these because dividing by zero doesn't do anything useful in C. [The arctangent of positive and negative infinity are π/2 and -π/2, respectively.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[atan%28-inf%29%2C%20atan%28%2Binf%29])

Comment: Of course... this is what I was looking for. Totally forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind being always pi/2 or -pi/2 is because of the definition of Polar coordinates. A polar point is described by P(r, Phi). So, if X is 0 (and y != 0) the only possibilities are 90° and 270° => PI/2 and -PI/2

The distance on the Y axis is defined by 'r'

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Polar_graph_paper.svg

::edit::

added: "and y != 0", ty chux

Comment: "So, if X is 0 the only possibilities are 90° and 270° => PI/2 and -PI/2" ignores the corner cases when `x` and `y` are both +/-0.0. "A domain error may occur if both arguments are zero." C11dr §7.12.4.4 2